# Chart JS in LWC : Data Labels are not coming in charts

Tags: lightning-web-components, charts

I'm using using chart JS 3.8 as provided in trailhead repo & chartjs-plugin-datalabel v2 to show datalabels in my line chart but the charts are loading without any data labels.

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ChartJSV3';
import ChartDataLabels from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/ChartJSDataPluginV2';  
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

const generateRandomNumber = () => {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};


export default class GdcmsChartJsTrendChart extends LightningElement {
    error;
    chart;
    chartjsInitialized = false;

    config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [
                        generateRandomNumber(),
                        generateRandomNumber(),
                        generateRandomNumber(),
                        generateRandomNumber(),
                        generateRandomNumber()
                    ],
                    // datalabels: {
                    //     align: 'start',
                    //     anchor: 'start'
                    // },
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                        'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
                        'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
                        'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                        'rgb(54, 162, 235)'
                    ],
                    label: 'Dataset 1',
                    // datalabels: {
                    //     align: 'end',
                    //     anchor: 'end'
                    //   }
                }
            ],
            labels: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue']
        },
        options: {
            responsive: false,
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'right'
                },
                datalabels: {
                    anchor: 'end',
                    align: 'end',
                    labels: {
                        value: {
                            color: 'blue'
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true
            },
        },
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
            options: {
                responsive:false,
                datalabels: {
                    anchor: 'end',
                    align: 'end',
                    labels: {
                        value: {
                            color: 'blue'
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
    };

    async renderedCallback() {
        if (this.chartjsInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.chartjsInitialized = true;

        try {
            await loadScript(this, chartjs);
            await loadScript(this, ChartDataLabels);
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            this.template.querySelector('div.chart').appendChild(canvas);
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);

        } catch (error) {
            this.error = error;
            console.error('chart error: ' + error);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]